# pgadmin4 Local Server password

Tags: python, pgadmin

When I try to run pgadmin4 in the Anaconda Prompt there is no request for me to set username or password.

As a result, when I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:5050 I am unable to login.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a replacement for the documentation. A master password is pre-generated, there's no "default password"

Comment: The online info says it will ask me to create a user and a password? https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python/

Comment: What if you try to run the command outside the anaconda prompt from your regular system terminal?

Comment: I must admit to being useless here. Presuming you just mean to type in "pgadmin4", I return 'pgadmin4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Looking at the page you linked to, did you 1) Create a virtual environment (not a Conda environment) 2) Did you `activate` that virtual environment, then run the command?